# Assertion failure in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, assertion

I am doing an application for iPad. I have a `UISplitViewController`, and if I use selection push (and if I set for this the destination `DetailSplitViewController`) in UITableView Controller for one of my several View Controller, application crashes. This error has to give:

```
05/20/2014 13:59:32.439 Units [1534:60 b] *** Assertion failure in - [UIStoryboardPushSegue perform] / SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIStoryboardBuiltInSegues.m: 24
05/20/2014 13:59:32.441 Units [1534:60 b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected a navigation controller, but got an instance of' UIViewController 'instead, while performing a split view controller push segue (identifier'') for index # 1 '
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017788e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6c048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x0114b4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x007a0ac4 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue perform] + 854
    5   UIKit                               0x0078ff0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    6   UIKit                               0x0078ff87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    7   UIKit                               0x00315965 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1453
    8   UIKit                               0x00315b14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    9   UIKit                               0x0031a10e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    10  UIKit                               0x002490aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    11  UIKit                               0x00249055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    12  UIKit                               0x00248e76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3436e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02b342bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02b12254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02b119d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02b117eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02dc95ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x02dc942b GSEventRun + 104
    20  UIKit                               0x0022bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    21  Jednotky                            0x0000dc2d main + 141
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0640e701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

As the reason already tells you

```
'Expected a navigation controller, but got an instance of' UIViewController 'instead'
```

Seems like you try to push a UIViewController, but you need to push a UIViewController wrapped in an **UINavigationController**

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a beginner, can you please tell me how to do it?